# dojox.grid.DataGrid's scroll reaches at top when scrolling in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, dojox.grid.datagrid

I have a dojox.grid.DataGrid. In this the problem is when i scroll down in the grid with mouse trackwheel then it again loads the data in the grid and the scroll again goes to top. Here is my code :

grid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
        id: 'grid_spark',
        store: store,
        structure: layoutBooks,
        columnReordering:"true",
        rowSelector: '0px',
        onRowClick:function(e){
            var l_row   =   e.rowIndex;
            var l_cell  =   grid.getItem(l_row);
            for (var i in l_cell){
               // alert(i+' = '+l_cell[i]);
            }
            if(radio_clicked_flag){
                selected_row_data.target_id             =   this.store.getValue(l_cell, "target_id");
                selected_row_data.target_name           =   this.store.getValue(l_cell, "report_name");
                selected_row_data.energy_parameter      =   this.store.getValue(l_cell, "energy_parameter");
                selected_row_data.target_value          =   this.store.getValue(l_cell, "target_value");
                selected_row_data.target_type           =   this.store.getValue(l_cell, "target_type");
                selected_row_data.created_by            =   this.store.getValue(l_cell, "created_by");
                selected_row_data.roll_up               =   this.store.getValue(l_cell, "roll_up");
                selected_row_data.equip_id              =   this.store.getValue(l_cell, "equip_id");
                selected_row_data.equip_name            =   this.store.getValue(l_cell, "equip_name");
                selected_row_data.meter_list            =   this.store.getValue(l_cell, "mater_list");
            }
            radio_clicked_flag=false;
        }}
        ,dojo.byId("grid5"));

What is the best possible way to avoid/remove this problem. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem ! Here's a workaround:

You have to initialize the grid with

> **autoHeight:true**

Then scrolling should work fine !

> new dojox.grid.DataGrid({id:'grid_spark', store:
>   store,...,**autoHeight:true**,...

**But notice:** This will render every row and keep it in memory. That is why it takes longer to load, especially when you have many rows.

Lucian